# NotesMIMEEntity is null when opening document using sessionAsSigner

Tags: xpages

On a XPage I'm using the following code to load some text from a document's MIME entity:

```
var dcl:NotesDocumentCollection=database.getView("myView").getAllDocumentsByKey("key",true);
var doc:NotesDocument=dcl.getFirstDocument();
var entity:NotesMIMEEntity=doc.getMIMEEntity("data");
var text=entity.getContentAsText();
```

This works without errors. When replacing **database** with **sessionAsSigner.getCurrentDatabase()** an error is raised, stating that the **MIME entity is null** (testing environment = Server: Notes 8.5.3 | Client: Firefox 15). Here is some additional information I got from manually debugging the code:

- sessionAsSigner is a valid NotesSession object
- doc is a valid NotesDocument that is readable for me, i.e. using the
  getItemValue methods works without error
- doc.hasItem("data") is true, i.e. the MIME entity field exists

However, using doc.getMIMEEntity("data") returns null even though it's not empty. The problem even occurs for documents without authors and readers fields. Why does using **sessionAsSigner** allow to open the document and get item values, but not allow to read the MIME entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue, call

```
sessionAsSigner.setConvertMime(false);
```

before using the sessionAsSigner object. This prevents MIME items from being converted to rich text when opening a document. Otherwise NotesDocument.getMIMEEntity returns null.